# Error using column from main query in subquery

Tags: mysql, select

I'm not an advanced mysql user, so you will have to bear with me on this.

I am trying to use the `cref` variable in one of the subqueries, but I am getting an error that the `cref` column does not exist. If I take the subquery out it will display the  column, so the column definitely exists.

Also if there are any other mistakes, would appreciate the heads up :)

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  (contractorsRef) AS cref,
  RIDGROUP AS ridg,
  (
    SELECT count(*) FROM (
      SELECT DISTINCT subcontractorRef
      FROM request
      INNER JOIN request_config
        ON request_config.RIDGROUP = request.RIDGROUP
      WHERE request_config.contractorsRef = cref  --### ERROR HERE
        AND currenttaxyear =2011
        AND weekno =31
  ) AS xx
) as xxx
FROM request_config
WHERE currenttaxyear =2011
  AND weekno =32
  AND contractorsRef <>132
```

Answer (score 0):

try this (note that I labeled the `request_config` in the outer select as  `outer_config` and I qualified the reference in the inner select with the label

```
SELECT DISTINCT (contractorsRef) AS cref, RIDGROUP AS ridg, 
    (select count(DISTINCT subcontractorRef)
    FROM request
    INNER JOIN request_config ON request_config.RIDGROUP = request.RIDGROUP
    WHERE request_config.contractorsRef = outer_config.contractorsRef 
    AND currenttaxyear =2011
    AND weekno =31) AS xxx
FROM request_config outer_config
WHERE currenttaxyear =2011
AND weekno =32
AND contractorsRef <>132
```

**EDIT**
pls try again, I removed 1 unnecessary layer from the subselect

Comment: , sorry. it says
#1054 - Unknown column 'outer_config.contractorsRef' in 'where clause'nope

Comment: OK, could you pls give it an other try?

Comment: this is what I had orginally, but the count(DISTINCT subcontractorRef) is causing a slow query so I read up the count(*) and then using a subquery for it to speeden it. Any other ideas?

Comment: I see. In this case I really suggest you to post your working query in a new post and ask SO how to speed it up. This subquery thing won't speed it up IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Subqueries are executed first and their results are used as input to the outer query. So while you *are* creating the coulmn `cref` in your outer query, it *does not yet exist* when your subquery is being executed.

You can probably solve your problem by merging the two queries. Start with your subquery, and join with `request_config`. Then add the appropriate conditions, and the appropriate columns